# ImageMagick displays garbled text instead of image

Tags: php, imagemagick

I am trying to use ImageMagick class functions in PHP.
To get familiar with ImageMagick, I wrote a few lines of code in PHP to display a red square in my browser.

Instead of displaying a red square, I get garbled text.
I know ImageMagick is installed because I can use ImageMagick functions to save the red square to a file.

Thanks in advance for any help for this newbie to ImageMagick and StackOverflow!

Here's my PHP code:

```
$image = new Imagick();
$image->newImage(100, 100, new ImagickPixel('red'));
$image->setImageFormat('png');
$image->writeImage("MyOutput.png");

header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $image;  //This causes just raw text to be displayed. :(

echo '<img src=MyOutput.png>'; //Displays a 100x100 red image!
                               //..So, ImageMagick IS installed.
```

Here's my full PHP file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>ImageMagick Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

$image = new Imagick();
$image->newImage(100, 100, new ImagickPixel('red'));
$image->setImageFormat('png');

header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $image;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem you have is that you're sending `Content-Type: image/png` after putting some output. Once you put any output, PHP immediately sends all response headers and proceeds to the body part of response. The default `Content-Type` is `text/html` on most servers, so your browser is interpreting image content as HTML, and thats why you're seeing some garbage. It's a bit like opening PNG file in notepad.

[See this question for more information about sending response headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Also you can't return HTML and image content upon one request, so **do not put any HTML** in your image-generating file. The image is independent file and it has to be returned upon it's own, separate request, containing only headers, image bytes and nothing more.

This should work:

```
<?php
$image = new Imagick();
$image->newImage(100, 100, new ImagickPixel('red'));
$image->setImageFormat('png');

header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $image;
```

Note, that this is whole PHP file and you can't send any other output neither from outside of `<?php ?>` nor by echoing.

If you want to include your image into HTML you need a second file (it may be plain HTML), which should look as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>ImageMagick Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- here we're including our image-generating PHP script -->
    <img src="imagickTest.php">
</body>
</html>
```

Then you can refer either to PHP file if you want to see only image or to HTML file if you want to see image put into HTML context.

Comment: That didn't work.  Here's my PHP file.  It still displays garbled text instead of an image:

`<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
      <title>ImageMagick Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>

<?php

$image = new Imagick();
$image->newImage(100, 100, new ImagickPixel('red'));
$image->setImageFormat('png');

header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $image;

?>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: That worked!  Thanks for taking the time to give me a detailed explanation, pamelus.  I really appreciate it!

Comment: @pamelus I have some problems using this method when I try to use a pdf url that is stored in a variable. Could you possibly help me?